# Store binary file in OrientDB using pyorient

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I am trying to store a binary file in OrientDB. I am using pyorient. The file can be large (more than 50mb) and I could not find a way except for storing its hex as a list of strings which takes a long time to store. Is there a way I can do it in a more elegant way and get done faster?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think not; I spent a bunch of time on this and OrientDB's ability to store binary files isn't exposed in PyOrient as far as I could tell.

As you may know, PyOrient hasn't received an update since 2017 (I assume no longer officially supported) and none of the more recent features in the database are available via the PyOrient driver either.

Personally I've reached the conclusion that OrientDB is no longer a viable choice for a Python based solution even without the binary file limitation, unless you have the time/energy to dig into the driver and bring it up to spec.